# Is there any way to stop Lego StarWars from overwriting saves?

Tags: lego-star-wars

So I have been playing Lego Star Wars with my little brother, but he doesn't really understand that when he starts a new game instead of using load game, the save overwrites. I have told him multiple times about this but that doesn't stop him from accidentally pressing it from time to time.

Is there any way to block the new game option or to ensure he doesn't save over the old game?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, when you create a new game on LEGO Star Wars, it asks you to pick a save slot. Chances are, he will be just clicking through the dialogue which means it'll be overwriting save slot 1. If you don't want him to overwrite your save, I'd move it to another slot that's available

Answer (score 0):

If you are on PC then you could back-up your saves manually. To do that you have to first find the save files than make a backup copy, and when you want to start playing again you can manually overwrite the save files with your copy.

The exact location of saves depends on the operating system and the version of the game you are using.

If you are playing on a Windows 7 and it is the Lego Star Wars: The Complete Saga then the save folder would be at:

`C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Lucasarts\LEGO Star Wars - The Complete Saga\SavedGames\`

Of course you have to replace {USER} with your username, and the AppData folder is hidden.